Clipping x, y to z = 0.1
There is a rule in 3D software's where you cannot draw behind the camera so I want to clip the vertices x, y coordinates to z = 0.1 using this code:
function clipZ(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, z) {
  const t = (z - z1) / (z2 - z1);
  const x = x1 + t * (x2 - x1);
  const y = y1 + t * (y2 - y1);
  return [x, y, z];
}

This is the replit: replit.com/js-3d-2#script.js
I have tried clipping the vert. directly to Z although when clipping we need to create new vertices and I don't know how to do that.
